# Required attribute for selectlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
[Required]
public SelectList CustomerLocations { get; set; }

Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerLocationID, Model.CustomerLocations)
```

When ddl doesnt have items attribute doesnt work

Comment: You don't apply the attribute to the `SelectList` property, you apply it to the `CustomerLocationID` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to below code it's work.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your reason for contacting is required.")]
public int CustomerLocationID { get; set; }

Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerLocationID,Model.CustomerLocations)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerLocations)
```

Comment: Glad to help you . :)